# Is it bad idea to store my passwords on blockchain with a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, security

I want to save my passwords and some other personal data on a ethereum like blockchain. it seems more persistant to me. I may lose my e-mail , my pc may crush and I may lose my usb stick. But nothing will happen to a blockchain.

I will encryp it and put `require(msg.sender,myaddress);` to even read functions. But still is there a way someone else can retrieve these information as it would be very bad because they could just easily login to my wallets with that info and steal funds.

Comment: We don't need to invoke your contract functions in order  to read your contract data (state variables).

Comment: even if they aren't public? how would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing secret in Ethereum blockchain. So, yes, it would be an extremely bad idea to store password there.

Even if a variable is `private` it only means it can't be read directly by other smart contract. But everyone outside the blockchain can get the data if they want to. There are two approaches:

1. See what transactions the contract has received and read their data (that data can't be hidden)
2. Analyze the contract state from your client (a lot more difficult approach)

Comment: Then how does Storj work? I thought saving encrypted data on the blockchain was already an established use case.

Comment: no idea how storj works.